# DATE repeating until the while loop fetches records

Tags: php, function, date

Please check the image, it will explain visually

http://dubads.com/temp/Untitled-1.jpg

```
for ($index = 1; $index <= $numdays; $index++) {

    $users =
        "SELECT invoice_date, DAY(invoice_date) as invoiceday, " .
        "sum(total_amount) as fullamount from invoices " .
        "WHERE MONTH(invoice_date)='".$month."' AND YEAR(invoice_date)='".$year.
        "' GROUP BY invoiceday";
    $res = mysql_query($users);
    $row = mysql_num_rows($res);

    while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {

        echo "<tr id='".(($j % 2 == 0) ? 'row3' : 'row4')."'>";

        $explodedate = explode("-", $fetch['invoice_date']);
        $days = $explodedate[2];
        $month1 = $explodedate[1];
        $year1 = $explodedate[0];

        $dates = date("jS", strtotime($fetch['invoice_date']));

        echo "<td style='text-align:left;padding-left:12px'>".$index.
            "</td>";
        if ($index == $dates) {

            echo "<td style='text-align:right;padding-right:12px'>".
                $fetch['fullamount']."</td>";

        } else {

            echo "<td style='text-align:right;padding-right:12px'>--</td>";

        }

        echo "</tr>";
    }
}

$total =
    "SELECT SUM(total_amount) as fulltotal from invoices where MONTH(invoice_date)='".
    $month1."' AND YEAR(invoice_date)='".$year1."';";

$totres = mysql_query($total);
$totfetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($totres);
if ($totfetch['fulltotal'] == "") {
    echo "<tr><td>NOTHING FOUND</td></tr>";
} else {
    ECHO "<TR>";
    echo "<td style='color:#BD0000;padding-left:12px;border:1px solid #ccc;width:20%;height:40px;text-align:left'>TOTAL AMOUNT </td>";
    echo "<td style='color:#BD0000;border:1px solid #ccc;width:20%;height:40px;text-align:right;padding-right:12px'>".$totfetch['fulltotal']."</TD></TR>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: A bit more explanation would be in order, even with the image! And please shorten your code by taking out everything that is not relevant to the quesiton.

Comment: He needs to calculate the sum of all values for a specific date in the sql call.

Comment: If you see the image, the sum is already calculated. There is no problem with the amount and or anything related to the query. As I said the problem is that the day is repeating. The values of invoice is also placed in the correct row (day), the only thing is it is not outputting the month once. If there is more than one record, it will repeat the days of the month, and the repetition count of month will be same as the count of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got one loop counting $index. I would recomment to make indexes 0-based, but that is not your problem:

You have got the outer loop:

```
for ($index = 1; $index <= $numdays; $index++) {
    ...
}
```

And in it you have the inner loop, wich is doing the output for each record:

```
while ($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    ...
}
```

So for each day you output all the records returned by your query.

I can not give you any suggestions, how to solve this, because I can not see, what you want to do. Maybe you could explain, which records schould be shown, when!

Oh and you have got an error in your html syntax! An ID has to be unique. In your case you should use class not id!

Edit:

Ahh.. Ok i think I can imagine, what you mean!

You want to have one line per day and for an empty day you want also an empty line...

Actually that is fairly easy I start writing it... Might take about 5 minutes!

Edit No.2:

```
for ($index = 0; $index < $numdays; $index++)
{

    $sql =
        'SELECT sum(total_amount) as fullamount from invoices ' .
        'WHERE MONTH(invoice_date)=\'' . $month . '\' AND YEAR(invoice_date)=\'' . $year .
        '\' And DAY(invoice_date)=\'' . ($index+1) . '\';';

    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res))

    echo '<tr class=\'' . (($j % 2 == 0) ? 'row3' : 'row4') . '\'>' . "\n";
    echo '<td style=\'text-align:left;padding-left:12px\'>' . ($index+1) . '</td>' . "\n";

    if($row['fullamount']!=null&&$row['fullamount']!=''&&$row['fullamount']!=0)
    {
        echo '<td style=\'text-align:right;padding-right:12px\'>' . $row['fullamount'] . '</td>' . "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<td style=\'text-align:right;padding-right:12px\'>--</td>' . "\n";
    }

    echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}

$sql =
    'SELECT SUM(total_amount) as fulltotal from invoices where MONTH(invoice_date)=\'' .
    $month . '\' AND YEAR(invoice_date)=\'' . $year . '\';';

$res = mysql_query($sqö);
$fetch = mysql_fetch_array($res);

if ($fetch['fulltotal'] == '')
{
    echo '<tr><td>NOTHING FOUND</td></tr>';
}
else
{
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";
    echo '<td style=\'color:#BD0000;padding-left:12px;border:1px solid #ccc;width:20%;height:40px;text-align:left\'>TOTAL AMOUNT </td>' . "\n";
    echo '<td style=\'color:#BD0000;border:1px solid #ccc;width:20%;height:40px;text-align:right;padding-right:12px\'>' . $fetch['fulltotal'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>' . "\n";
}

echo '</table>';
```

I hope, this helps you! good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can view a this working at http://qasqoos.nsegulf.com/daily_sales_temp.php It will be showing this month. Because there are invoices only for one day, it shows the month days only once. Just go back to previous month and you will understand what I mean. With regards to the id, it is not creating any problems with the table.

Comment: Thanks very much. It is working now. Please check the same link. I have updated the code with your solution. The only change I did was '\' And DAY(invoice_date)=\'' . ($index+1) . '\';'; [TO] '\' And DAY(invoice_date)=\'' . $index . '\';'; as it was not showing the current month's day one's invoices's amount.